# "addressing" a series in a multi time-frame context in Pine-Script

Tags: pine-script

Suppose i want to work with multi-time frame series

for example we have the hourly series

```
s = security (tickerid, "60", close)
```

while working on a 5minute chart.

in the context of a 5mn chart, s will look like a step function which change value every 12 bars (== every hour) and s[1] would return 11 times out of 12 the same value than the current value of s.

Suppose I want to build a strategy where i put some conditions on the hourly series, for example a bullish price flip to happen

```
priceflip = s > s[4] and s[1] < s[5]
```

is what i would write if i was working on hourly charts

but in a 5mns context, that expression would return probably false all the time (think why !)
the dirty way to solve the problem is to write

```
priceflip = s > s[4*12] and s[1*12] s< s[5*12]
```

thats quite unelegant to me because if we change timeframes, then all multipliers change.

Is there a more "functional-language" or elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for security() function. It is buggy and causes repainting issue. More explained here: https://www.tradingview.com/script/JwWWwZOD-RSI-MTF-by-PeterO/